# why I ommit the return keyword and the result also be correct

Tags: c

The confusing code is marked in the comment.

why it can still return 89 to main() correctly? I obviously ommit return.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int(*FunPtr)();

int callback()
{
    return 89;
}

int fun()
{
    FunPtr ptr = callback;
    ptr(); /* here */
}

int main()
{
    int ret = fun();
    printf("%d\n",ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of undefined behavior

Comment: The return value of a function is generally in a register that depends on architecture, but is always the same for a given compiler/arch. When returning from `callback`, 89 is put in this register. This value is not overwritten by `fun()` (that does not return anything) and remains identical when read by `main()`. But you should *never* rely on it.